# unable to write Base64 image data on FTP server

Tags: java, ftp, base64, filewriter

I have encountered the problem to write Base64image data on FTP. 
When I write it on local drive, The photo is appeared clearly.
But, When I write it on FTP server, it's appeared like spoiled images. 
when I write it on local drive, it's shown like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EveJA.jpg)
I have attached the picture on FTP . [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FlzD.jpg)

Here is my code.

```
  private static String testFilesDir = "C:\\Storage";
public String getIncidentPhotoByID(int incident_id, int photoId) {
    String base64Image = null;
    WebSSLClient client = new WebSSLClient();

    Response response =client.createRequest(PropertiesUtil.getOracleCloudRestUrL() + "/mobile/platform/storage/collections/incident_photos_collection/objects/incident_462_03").get();

    String jsonResponse = response.readEntity(String.class);

            base64Image = jsonResponse;
                FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();  
                FileInputStream fis = null;
                String filename = "incident_462_03";

                String[] strings = base64Image.split(",");
                String extension;
                   switch (strings[0]) {//check image's extension
                       case "data:image/jpeg;base64":
                           extension = "jpeg";
                           break;
                       case "data:image/png;base64":
                           extension = "png";
                           break;
                       default://should write cases for more images types
                           extension = "jpg";
                           break;
                   }
                //convert base64 string to binary data

                   byte[] data1 = Base64.decodeBase64(strings[1]);
                 /*
                   String path = testFilesDir+"/"+filename+"."+ extension;
                   File file = new File(path);
                   try (OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))) {
                       outputStream.write(data1);
                   } catch (IOException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   } */

                   try  {  

                       ftp.connect("link.myjpl.com");
                       ftp.login("user", "password");
                       String path = "Images/test/"+filename+"."+ extension;
                       OutputStream out1 = ftp.storeFileStream(path);
                       out1.write(data1);
                       ftp.logout();

                   } catch (IOException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   } 

    return base64Image;
}
```

}

Comment: try `out1.flush();`

Comment: I added that after out1.write(data1); . The image is shown the same.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yes, I have attached the original pic and corrupted pic. The code is  also there.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I have put commented code  which writes image into local. And the code below commented code also writes into FTP.

Comment: Try setting the fileType to `FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE`  Also as per the javadocs *To finalize the file transfer you must call completePendingCommand and check its return value to verify success.*

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yeah! Thank you. It works now.

Comment: That's cool - have a good day.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I still have another question. I tried to write multiple file using while condition after connection opened. But, it writes only one file. other 2 files weren't written on FTP. Could you please guide me. Thanks a lot

Comment: If you have a new problem, as a new question, including a code relevant to the new problem.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thank you so much. I have raised another problem. Here is a link.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52963235/unable-to-write-multiple-file-on-ftp-server

Comment: @ScaryWombat Could you please answer this post? "Try setting the fileType to FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE" instead of comment. I want to accept the answer  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the fileType to `FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE`. Also as per the javadocs, to finalize the file transfer you must call `completePendingCommand` and check its return value to verify success.

See https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#storeFileStream(java.lang.String)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thanks for the edit.  This guy finally got it sorted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52963235/unable-to-write-multiple-file-on-ftp-server