# Unable to write multiple file on FTP server

Tags: java, file-upload, ftp, base64

Hello I have got error such as java.lang.NullPointerException on  OutputStream out = ftp.storeFileStream(path);.  after I write one file and was not able to continue to write second files on FTP server.

Could you please help me?  the code wrote 1st image and stopped writing it at all. 
Here is my method code ........

```
    public void getIncidentPhotoByID(int incidentid, int photoId) {
    String base64Image = null;
    WebSSLClient client = new WebSSLClient();
    String photo_Id= "incident_"+incidentid;
    String jsonResponse,jsonResImg; 
    Response response =client.createRequest(PropertiesUtil.getOracleCloudRestUrL() + "/mobile/platform/storage/collections/dev_cre_incident_photos_collection/objects").get();
    jsonResponse = response.readEntity(String.class); 
    Map<String,String> imgMap = new HashMap<>();     
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
        JSONArray jsonArr = jsonObj.getJSONArray("items");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); ++i) {
            JSONObject rec = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
            String name = rec.getString("name");             
            String name_id = removeStr(name);
            if(name_id.equals(photo_Id)){ 
                Response response1 =client.createRequest(PropertiesUtil.getOracleCloudRestUrL() + "/mobile/platform/storage/collections/dev_cre_incident_photos_collection/objects/"+name).get();
                jsonResImg = response1.readEntity(String.class); 
                imgMap.put(name, jsonResImg);
            }           
        }            
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
```

I will post 2 separate codes. It's one method in fact.

```
    FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();  
    FileInputStream fis = null;
     try  {                 
          ftp.connect("link.myjpl.com");
          ftp.login("user", "password");
          ftp.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            Set set;
            set = imgMap.entrySet();
            Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry mentry = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();

                base64Image = mentry.getValue().toString();
                      System.out.println(base64Image);
                String filename =  mentry.getKey().toString();
                     System.out.println(filename);
                String[] strings = base64Image.split(",");
                String extension;
                   switch (strings[0]) {//check image's extension
                       case "data:image/jpeg;base64":
                           extension = "jpeg";
                           break;
                       case "data:image/png;base64":
                           extension = "png";
                           break;
                       default://should write cases for more images types
                           extension = "jpg";
                           break;
                   }   
                       byte[] data1 = Base64.decodeBase64(strings[1]);
                       String dirPath ="ReportImages/test/";
                       String dir = dirPath+photo_Id;
                       boolean dirExists = ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(dir);
                       if(!dirExists){
                           ftp.makeDirectory(dir);  
                       }
                       String path = dir+"/"+filename+"."+ extension;                        

                       OutputStream out = ftp.storeFileStream(path);
                       out.write(data1); 
                       ftp.completePendingCommand();
                       out.flush();
             }
                    ftp.disconnect();                             
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.print(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error while FTP'ing ");   
        } 
}
```

Here is NPE error!

```
SEVERE:
```

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.scm.cre.cloud.model.services.CareCloudDbAppModuleImpl.getIncidentPhotoByID(CareCloudDbAppModuleImpl.java:144)
    at com.scm.cre.batch.job.ConnectTest.callRestAip(ConnectTest.java:20)
    at com.scm.cre.batch.CareExecutor.main(CareExecutor.java:84)

Process exited with exit code 1.
Here is a screen shot....
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eFrL.png)

Comment: Can you post stacktrace for NPE?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yeah! I added ftp.completePendingCommand() . But, still the same error.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl According to first line of his question *java.lang.NullPointerException on out.write(data1)*, but would still be good to see a text based stacktrace

Comment: @ScaryWombat True, I didn't notice. Sorry.

Comment: 1) Move `completePendingCommand` after `out.flush()`. 2) Call `ftp.getReplyString()` after `storeFileStream` and check what does it return. 3) It would be very nice, if you post [mcve] - i.e. an upload of two local files or chunks of data, without the all the other code that's irrelevant to your question.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl still same error!  I moved completePendingCommand after out.flush() and add ftp.getReplyString() after out.write(data1); which is Line 144.

Comment: `e.printStackTrace();` is going to give you more useful output, please give **us** a decent stacktrace

Comment: @ScaryWombat  I attached error screen shot. I can download them into local drive. But it happens error while uploading on FTP.

Comment: change `ftp.getReplyString()` to `System.out.println (ftp.getReplyString());` **AND** wrap `out.write(data1);` with a `try-catch` block

Comment: @ScaryWombat When I debug it , OutputStream out = ftp.storeFileStream(path); got null on second loop. Data is there . But unable to store file .

Comment: How can you get NPE on `ftp.storeFileStream(path)`? `ftp` cannot become `null`. Are you sure? Do you get still the same stacktrace?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yeah! still same error.  on second loop, ftp.storeFileStream(path) become null.

Comment: *"ftp.storeFileStream(path) become null"* is not the same as *"got error such as java.lang.NullPointerException on OutputStream out = ftp.storeFileStream(path);"* - You are confusing us! You get NPE on `out.write(data1)` because `ftp.storeFileStream(path)` returns `null`. And we know that already for a while. So give us the information we asked for, instead of repeating what we know already.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl But, I found out when i debug step by step... since it's unable to store file, data can't be written as well.  I am still finding the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a look at the [javadocs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#storeFileStream(java.lang.String))

it says:

*If the data connection cannot be opened (e.g., the file does not exist), null is returned (in which case you may check the reply code to determine the exact reason for failure).*

Therefore your code should do:

```
if (out == null) {
    System.out.println(ftp.getReplyCode());
    System.out.println (ftp.getReplyString());
}
```

In my case the reason is

*550 Permission denied.*

which in my case was curable by editing /etc/vsftpd.conf

and changing to

**write_enable=YES**

Save the file and restart vsftpd with sudo service vsftpd restart.

**here** is a fuller example

```
FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();

try {
    ftp.connect("somehost");
    ftp.login("user", "pw");
    ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();

    OutputStream out = ftp.storeFileStream("dump1");
    if (out == null) {
        System.out.println(ftp.getReplyCode());
        System.out.println (ftp.getReplyString());
        return;
    }
    out.write("test is a test".getBytes());
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    System.out.println (ftp.getReplyString());
    ftp.completePendingCommand();
    System.out.println (ftp.getReplyString());

    out = ftp.storeFileStream("dump2");
    if (out == null) {
        System.out.println(ftp.getReplyCode());
        System.out.println (ftp.getReplyString());
        return;
    }
    out.write("test is a test2".getBytes());
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    System.out.println (ftp.getReplyString());
    ftp.completePendingCommand();
    System.out.println (ftp.getReplyString());

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    finally {
        try {
            ftp.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, Thank you so much. Now, I see my error as "553 Could not create file.". Where can I find the vsftpd.conf. I am lost.

Comment: Well I am not even sure you are using vsftpd as your ftp server, please investigate.  I am guessing that even without using Java you would have trouble saving the file.

Comment: The thing is I can create first one. But, the second file failed to create file. Is write_enable=YES  for creating  multiple files within one connection stream?

Comment: copy and test my example

Comment: Wow. Your code works on my pc. all files  created....But, my code doesn't work. I  try to use getBytes().

Comment: Maybe the problem is with a not closing OutputStream b) not calling ftp.completePendingCommand();  c) filename ?

Comment: I have used a and b. I think the file name problem with extension.

Comment: I would love to share that I found the error. I added "/"  in front of the path. All files are stored successfully. Thank you so much for your time and guidance.

Comment: Great to hear, please consider to up vote and/or accept my answer

Comment: I want to vote. But, I ma not allowed to vote as I have less than 15 reputation. How to improve my reputation since I am new in Software Field?. Thank you.

Comment: You can accept my answer see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I did it and i gain 2 reputation. Feeling happy :)